# PHP / Apache, very weird redirect issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

with NO .htaccess in place, all requests to /login   go straight to /cart/register  which then goes to  /cart

no code in any of those files gets executed (PHP files)

there is nothing in the httpd.conf referencing "login" or "cart"

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: post your apache conf please - make sure it is the active one

Comment: Can you paste the login code here? Will need that in order to help. What cart is it? Is there a live link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not getting back sooner.  I figured it out.

Apparently Apache was sourcing the .htaccess in the *parent* folder of the https (ssl webroot) folder.  (?)

Must be a host configuration or something

Arg.  I want those hours of my life back!  :)

Thanks for stepping up, guys :)